# Copying packages from previous distro doesn't work

Tags: kubuntu

I am using apt-clone to clone all the packages from the distro I was using previously and in the new distro I am using sudo apt-clone restore ~/foo.apt-clone.tar.gz and it fetches nothing but doesn't produce an error. The distro I am using now is kbuntu 22.04lts and the one i was using before was linux mint 20.3

This is the result of:

Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).

OK

Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)

Comment: it's just that i have a lot of packages and i'd rather not reinstall them manually. Is there any other way to reinstall packages or is doing it manually the only way? Thanks for answering!

Comment: I thought manually meant that I have to do sudo apt install <package name> for all the packages I had previously installed. In that case I have no difficulty in doing it, it just seems long. But Im probability going to do that since doing apt-clone thing just made it I coundn't install any packages, like apt list would only show insttalled packages

Answer (score 2):

Your observation confirms common knowledge. You cannot just transplant packages from one distro to another and expect them to work. For many packages, it can even not be done between different Ubuntu versions, leave alone different distro's.

Instead, manage the packages with the dedicated tools of your distribution, APT in the case of Ubuntu.

Comment: So I can use APT to transfer packages? Or is i that i have to reinstall all packages using APT?

Comment: No, you cannot transfer packages from one distro to another, unless it concerns the same version of the distro. What you consider doing is a no go: you have to consider another strategy.